# What is the difference between datatype "object" and dtype('O') in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, types

I wanted to convert my Date column `(yyyy-mm-dd)` into type `datetime`. I checked its dtype and it was object. On converting it as `pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])`, the dtype changed to dtype('O'). I looked it up online and it had to something with numpy dtypes however I cannot find a concrete answer.

> Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you share the specific example?

Answer (score 2):

They are the same thing:

```
In [52]: x = np.empty(3, object)                                                                     
In [53]: x                                                                                           
Out[53]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [54]: x.dtype                                                                                     
Out[54]: dtype('O')
In [55]: x = np.empty(3, 'O')                                                                        
In [56]: x                                                                                           
Out[56]: array([None, None, None], dtype=object)
In [57]: x.dtype                                                                                     
Out[57]: dtype('O')
In [60]: np.empty(3, np.object_).dtype                                                               
Out[60]: dtype('O')
```

`numpy` (and `pandas` by extension) has various ways of referring to equivalent dtypes.  There's the single character, longer words, and (if applicable) python classes.

https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#arrays-dtypes

```
In [71]: dt = np.empty(3, object).dtype                                                              
In [72]: dt.type, dt.str, dt.num, dt.char                                                            
Out[72]: (numpy.object_, '|O', 17, 'O')
```

## pandas dates case

If I make a dataframe with a sting date, I get an object dtype Series.  In `pandas` strings are stored as python objects, with object dtype:

```
In [284]: df = pd.DataFrame(['2011-03-23'])                                                          
In [285]: df                                                                                         
Out[285]: 
            0
0  2011-03-23
In [286]: df[0]                                                                                      
Out[286]: 
0    2011-03-23
Name: 0, dtype: object
In [287]: df[0][0]                                                                                   
Out[287]: '2011-03-23'
```

applying `to_datetime` converts the string to a `datetime64` dtype.  This is a `numpy` dtype the represents datetimes.

```
In [288]: pd.to_datetime(df[0])                                                                      
Out[288]: 
0   2011-03-23
Name: 0, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

`pandas` has various date representations.

Comment: Okay thank you. I have some doubts. 
1.What do you mean by "pandas by extension". 
2. So if I understood this correctly, it means pandas and numpy both have different nomenclature for data types?

Answer (score 1):

Although I could not get why this was happening but when I tried `data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], errors='coerce')` , the column changed into datetime type as it was required.